# If $a+b=c$ and $a>b$, how do we prove that $a>c/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Say $a+b=c$ and $a>b$. Is it true then that $$a>\frac{c}{2}$$

How do we prove this?

Comment: hint, add $a$ to both sides of $a > b$. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, solved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a+b=c\\
a>b$$
Add them to get
$$2a+b>b+c \implies 2a >c$$